# joomla bootstrap 3. change container size if columns have modules

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla

i've build a joomla 3 template with bootstrap.
My template has 3 columns: left main and right.
How can i change main column width to 100% if left and right columns has no modules?
I found this example

```
    // Adjusting content width
if ($this->countModules('position-7') && $this->countModules('position-8'))
{
    $span = "span6";
}
elseif ($this->countModules('position-7') && !$this->countModules('position-8'))
{
    $span = "span9";
}
elseif (!$this->countModules('position-7') && $this->countModules('position-8'))
{
    $span = "span9";
}
else
{
    $span = "span12";
}
```

but i need to change $span with col-md. What is the correct syntax?

my index.php:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-2">
            <div id="main">                 
                <jdoc:include type="component" />                   
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-pull-8">
            <div id="left-column">
            <?php if($this->countModules('left')) : ?>
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="sidebar-nav" />
            <?php endif;?>
            </div>
            </div>
            <!---right-->
            <div class="col-md-2">
            <div id="right-column">
            <?php if($this->countModules('right')) : ?>
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="none" />
            <?php endif;?>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<div class="row-fluid">

<?php 
      if ($this->countModules('left') || $this->countModules('right')){ 
?>
      <!-- modules are enabled in left and or right module positions -->
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-2">
            <div id="main">                 
                <jdoc:include type="component" />                   
            </div>
      </div>

      <!---left-->
      <div class="col-md-2 col-md-pull-8">
            <div id="left-column">
            <?php if($this->countModules('left')) : ?>
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="sidebar-nav" />
            <?php endif;?>
            </div>
      </div>

      <!---right-->
      <div class="col-md-2">
            <div id="right-column">
            <?php if($this->countModules('right')) : ?>
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="none" />
            <?php endif;?>
            </div>
      </div>



<?php 
} else {
?>

      <!-- no modules are enabled in both the left and right module positions -->

       <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="main">                 
                <jdoc:include type="component" />                   
            </div>
      </div>


<?php 
} 
?>

</div> <!-- close row-fluid -->
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm pleased it worked for you @johnl  One of the things I like about Joomla templates is that with some php and css knowledge it's really easy to start bending the template index.php file to fit your needs.